# How to manage "versions" of documents in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Sometimes, I will have a new set of documents that will "replace" an old set of documents. I would like to still have access to the old set of documents for historical data analysis. However, I would like to primarily be only searching the new set of documents.

One solution to this problem appears to be to create a new index for each grouping. And only search the most recent set of indices. However, then there will be thousands of indices, growing every time an update happens. Is this the optimal strategy or is there another better method?

Since elasticsearch was originally made for search engine which must experience issues like this constaly, I'm surprised there is not a more apparent solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elastic search inbuilt versioning  system only  keeps track of version numbers on indexed documents , it doesn't maintain historical data.

This you will have to implement yourself. You can do this in multiple ways
1. You can store historical data in document itself

```
    {
      "id":1,
      "content":"abc",
      "version":[
                    {"timestamp":"2019-10-01","content":""},
                    {"timestamp":"2019-10-02","content":""}
                ]
    }
```

```
This will bloat your documents and if content is large will cause performance issue.
```

2. You can store different version documents in same index with different version 
   numbers.

```
  {
    "id":1,
    "context":"",
    "version":1
  },
  {
    "id":1,
    "context":"",
    "version":2,
    "Iscurrent":"true"
  }
```

3. You can maintain old version in a single index as(2) and latest version in a separate index . So two indexes:- old and new. I think this will be more suitable for your purpse

Comment: What do you think about using separate indices for each update, and having an index alias that that points to the latest index?

Comment: number of indices will become very large with time and with duplicate data for majority of documents. I think it is best to maintain two indices or monthly or weekly indices if you need to only compare data for a limited period. Also for multiple indices joins etc are not possible so if you need to perform some aggregation or filters it won't be possible in single queries

Comment: Which strategy did you went ahead with?

Comment: I haven't implemented yet. I think I'm going to use separate index per update (data-name-1, data-name-2), and set the alias (current-name).  And then use a rollover (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-rollover-index.html) each time I want to change indices. This seems like both the most elegant solution to me. To search all current indices, i can search current-\*. to search all historical indices, I can search data-\*. What do you think?